# Cgminer opencl-detection overrided autogen error

Tags: cgminer

So I am trying to install cgminer on my debian server. I've downloaded the latest nVidia drivers, tried many things but still can't get this work.
So this is the end of the log from autogen.sh:

```
config.status: executing libtool commands



------------------------------------------------------------------------
cgminer 3.6.4
------------------------------------------------------------------------


Configuration Options Summary:

  libcurl(GBT+getwork).: Enabled: -lcurl
  curses.TUI...........: FOUND: -lncurses
  OpenCL...............: Detection overrided. GPU mining support DISABLED
configure: error: No mining configured in
```

I've already tried to download the latest CUDA toolkit, but it didn't work either. On google I just found solutions for ATI/AMD cards. (btw. I have GeForce GT-9600)

Answer (score 14):

use
./autogen.sh --enable-opencl
instead of
./autogen.sh

Comment: I also needed to install the header files (On Ubuntu: apt-get install opencl-header)

Comment: 'opencl-header' should be plural: apt-get install opencl-headers

Answer (score 0):

I had to install `ocl-icd-opencl-dev` as well before `./autogen.sh --enable-opencl`

```
sudo apt-get install ocl-icd-opencl-dev
sudo ./autogen.sh --enable-opencl
```